# Why ci/cd runs only one job instead of two?

Tags: git, gitlab-ci, devops, cicd

```
.build_rules:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "uat"
      variables:
        IMG_TAG: "xyz}"
        DOCKERFILE: "filename.txt2"
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "uat"
      variables:
        IMG_TAG: "abc"
        DOCKERFILE: "filename.txt`
```

i have extended it as

```
.build_job:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "$IMG_TAG"
    - echo "$DOCKERFILE" 
  rules:
    - !reference [.build_rules, rules]
```

now expecting 2 outputs in build job but runs only first, why?

Comment: `rules:` only control whether a job runs or not -- it does not create additional jobs for each matching rule -- and, at most, one rule matches for any job... If you want multiple jobs with different variables, you should be looking at `parallel:matrix:` instead.